# Internet connection not working

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection

I'm having a problem, where my computer has absolutely no internet - neither over Ethernet or over Wi-Fi (using USB adapter).

I'm in an online (multiplayer) match and, suddenly, *Poof!* Attempting to reconnect. I exit out of the match and use Windows Troubleshooter. What I get is "There might be a problem with the driver for the Local Area Connection adapter" and "Windows couldn't automatically bind to an IP address" (or something similar).

So now, I'm stuck with a computer, that has no internet. How do I fix it?

```
ipconfig -all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Daniel-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e8ee:36dc:9d5f:c11a%19(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.26.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 302010454
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-31-74-79-00-1D-7D-07-36-DE
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e4f3:d331:bf7e:bb37%21(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.154.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 318787670
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-31-74-79-00-1D-7D-07-36-DE
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Additional information:

```
Device manager:

  Ethernet and Wi-Fi drivers installed (The Wi-Fi drivers are from an external source (Mini-Disk) and I'm guessing that the Ethernet drivers are built-in, since I can't remove them from my PC (only uninstall them)). I've tried uninstalling them both and restarting my PC (which fixed the problem the first time), but that (obviously) didn't work now.

System Restore:

  I tried reverting to a restore point (as that worked the second time), but (obviously), it also didn't work, because it decided not to work. The restore point was from the previous day (Windows Critical Update), but it said, that it couldn't copy the registry.
I tried even further back (~10 days), bit it said, that it was corrupted.
```

Previous occurrences:

```
Windows 7:

    I've had this problem once. I wasn't able to connect to the internet in any way. Well, except, for when I was using a Live CD* and wasn't booting into Windows 7. Then, uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers worked.

Windows 10:

    I've had this problem twice. First time: I wasn't able to connect to the internet. I can't say much more, since I just ran System Restore and that fixed it. Second time (when this question was asked): I wasn't able to connect to the internet, both in Windows 7 and in a Live CD*. System Restore didn't help, since it "Wasn't able to copy the registry" and then, because "It's corrupted" (Ran chkdsk /r; /f /r and /f /b /r, but it didn't work. I reset my PC as a "Last Resort Method" to fix my internet (because nothing was working). The great thing is, that you can tell Windows to keep your files and just uninstall apps, drivers and similar.
```

Comment: Can you [ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) the router when the problem occurs? If you don't know the router's IP address, issue the command `ipconfig | find "Default Gateway"` at a [command prompt](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/win8/cmd_prompt.php). Then issue the command `ping IP_address` where IP_Address is the default gateway address, e.g. `ping 192.168.0.1`. Does `ipconfig` even show an IP address for the system when the problem occurs?

Comment: Troubleshoot to figure out what the problem is. Start by testing wired, because that's simpler. When you have issues, see if the link light is still on. See if you still have an assigned IP address. See if you can ping the router. Try pinging or tracerouting out by IP address. See if other devices using the same Internet connection work. Once you know what works and doesn't work, you can focus on precisely what's needed for that particular thing to work.

Answer (score 1):

You have no Ethernet or wireless drivers installed. You'll need to get that dealt with first.

Comment: They don't have an x or exclamation mark on them in device manager?

Comment: Nope. All are okay.

Comment: Then try a `netsh winsock reset`and reboot

Comment: Okay. What now?

Comment: Ipconfig again to see if it's detecting the adapter

Comment: No, it isn't detecting it...                 it wants me to chat, but I'm one rep. short of being able to do that...

Comment: Ok when I get home, I'll try the next command to give you the right syntax

Comment: What's takin' ya so long?

Comment: You gonna respond?

Comment: It's the Easter weekend, and I haven't been home for a couple of days. If you want to figure it out yourself, try in the `netsh interface` menu. I just don't remember which command to reset the adapters

Answer (score 1):

When nothing works and you desperately need your internet, you're gonna have to reset your PC D: (Yeah, I didn't want to do it, but I did. At least I know what got uninstalled, so I can install it again... If I really need it...)

Comment: That option is **probably** not available on Windows 7 and lower. It **might** not be available on Windows 8 and 8.1.
(I haven't looked for it and obviously, haven't found it)

Comment: Were you running Windows 10? I had to do this on a computer the other day that had a similar issue.

Comment: Can you look at the tags, please? (Also, Yes)

Comment: My bad. Seems to be an issue in windows 10. Had one of my computers at home do exactly what you said above. Only option was to refresh seems to be the best I can find for the solution.

Comment: I've had this problem in Windows 7 and ever since that happened, I've been having it every 1 or 2 months... (I'm getting a feeling, that something is or was messing with my PC)

Comment: May Try this in future Reference to see if it fixes the Issue. [Windows 10 No Internet](http://www.bidnessetc.com/business/internet-not-working-in-windows-10-heres-the-fix/) I will do the same.